# jQuery and client side api patterns / frameworks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is really vague question but I am in the process of inheriting a rough-on-the-edges piece of jQuery for handling requests / responses to an API over JSON. Basically, each 'page' has a separate set of ajax calls and there is tremendous duplication.

I'm looking for a good blog post or maybe a jQuery plugin that separates out different dependancies for doing these requests. I'd like to keep it in jQuery. Like bundle up arguments, post, wait for response, and then delegate to a view. Something like Sammy looks interesting but might be too much.

thx

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this is to use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to write a series of tests (essentially documenting how the code currently functions) such that all the tests pass. Then, start refactoring it, and cleaning it up so it's easier to read, but the tests still pass. This way you still know that the code words the same way, but it's much easier to read.

Rewriting it from scratch might work if it's truly a mess, but it's likely that if you take that approach (rather that working to put a test suite around it incrementally, as you're refactoring it) that you'll wind up re-introducing bugs into the code that have already been fixed.

This doesn't sound like it's on the scale of [the Netscape mistake](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html), but it's a good story nonetheless.